# Rational points on the unit circle

Tags: nt.number-theory, rational-points, arithmetic-progression

Is anything known about any of the following questions about rational points on the unit circle? By “double point” I mean an element of $2C$, where $C$ is the group of rational points on the unit circle (i.e. Gaussian rationals with unit modulus, under multiplication).

1. Are there two rational points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ on the unit circle such that the numbers $y_1 + y_2$ and $y_1 - y_2$ are also the y-coordinates of rational points on the unit circle, except where $y_1$ or $y_2$ is zero?
2. Are there are three distinct double points on the unit circle whose y-coordinates are in arithmetic progression, other than the trivial case where the middle one is on the x-axis?
3. Are there two double points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ on the unit circle such that $y_1 + y_2$ is also the y-coordinate of a double point on the unit circle, excluding the trivial case where one of $y_1$, $y_2$, $y_1+y_2$ is zero?
4. Are there three distinct rational points on the unit circle whose y-coordinates are in arithmetic progression, where the common difference of this arithmetic progression is also the y-coordinate of a rational point on the unit circle, other than the trivial case where the middle point is on the x-axis?

Comment: The first question amounts to finding rational points on a surface of general type. I searched for points, but didn't find any that aren't on the lines $y_{1} = 0$ or $y_{2} = 0$.

Comment: Probably all are surfaces of general type.  Without the "double" condition, #2 is a K3 surface, and one example of such an AP is $(4/5,56/65,12/13)$.

Comment: Rational points on the circle are known to be of the form $\left(\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)$ ($t \in \mathbb{Z}$). Have you looked into this direction ?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Thanks. Yes, #2 and #3 have positive answers without the “double” condition. (3/5, 4/5, 1) is an even simpler AP. For #3, (5/13, -77/85) is a pair of circle points whose sum is also a circle point, and (104/185, 1276/3485) is an example in which both are positive. (For these it’s easy to find elliptic curves of non-zero rank whose rational points correspond to examples, so to find infinite families of examples.)

Comment: @JeanMarieBecker You mean $t\in\mathbb{Q}$, presumably? Yes, but it doesn’t lead to anything any more obviously tractable. I’m really wondering, since I‘m pretty ignorant of modern number theory, whether there are any techniques I might not know about that are applicable to this sort of question.

Comment: @Robin Houston Yes, you are right: $t \in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Recalling this question last week, I found a general two parameter solution to $1 + p^2 = u^2$, $1 + q^2 = v^2$, $1 + r^2 = (u - v)^2$. So that set is a rational surface (over $Q$). But on checking this page again, I find the OP is asking for a different system (or combination of these), one being $p^2 + u^2 = 1$, $q^2 + v^2 = 1$ $r^2 + (u - v)^2 = 1$. Drat! I'll study the second one, as a two-parameter solution of that will greatly narrow down your search for Question 1. Please email me at jhnrmsdn@yahoo.co.uk if the solution of the first may also be relevant to you and and I'll post it here.